# Ansible using delegate_to with different ansible_ssh_common_args

Tags: ansible, suse, sles

I'm trying to make a run from my ansible master to a host (lets call it hostclient) which requires performing something into another host (let's call it susemanagerhost :) ).

hostclient needs `ansible_ssh_common_args` with proxycommand fullfilled, while susemanager host needs no `ansible_ssh_common_args` since its a direct connection.

So I thought I could use `delegate_to`, but the host called hostclient and the host called susemanagerhost have different values for the variable `ansible_ssh_common_args`.

I thought I could change the value of `ansible_ssh_common_args` inside the run with `set_fact` of `ansible_ssh_common_args` to `ansible_ssh_common_args_backup` (because I want to recover the original value for the other standard tasks) and then `ansible_ssh_common_args` to `null` (the connection from the ansible master to susemanager host is a direct connection with no proxycommand required) but it is not working.
It seems like its still using the original value for `ansible_ssh_common_args`.

Comment: Please add a little more detail, like error messages etc.

Comment: The error is that the task with delegate_to is a connection error , when I turn the -vvv I see its still using the old ansible_ssh_common_args and thats the reason of the connection error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ansible_ssh_common_args` is generally used to execute commands 'through' a proxy server:

```
<ansible system> => <proxy system> => <intended host>
```

The way you formulated your question you won't need to use `ansible_ssh_common_args` and can stick to using `delegate_to`:

```yaml
- name: execute on host client
  shell: ls -la

- name: execute on susemanagerhost
  shell: ls -la
  delegate_to: "root@susemanagerhost"
```

Call this play with:

```
ansible-playbook <play> --limit=hostclient
```

This should do it.

Edit:
After filing a bug on github the working solution is to have:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa ansible@{{ jumphost_server }}"'
```

In `host_vars` or `group_vars`.
Followed by a static use of `delegate_to`:

```
delegate_to: <hostname>
```

`hostname` should be the hostname as used by ansible.

But not use:

```
delegate_to: "username@hostname"
```

This resolved the issue for me, hope it works out for you as well.

Comment: Hello thanks, the problem is that I need ansible_ssh_common_args because I arrive to my client nodes using an intermedia te ssh proxy as you said, but I have a run where I want tu unsubscribe  one susemanager client from susemanager server, and that require me throwing stuff to the client, using the ssh args, and also throwing stuff to the susemanager server, but I cant use the same ssh args for the susemanager server because I have no proxy, instead I have a directo ssh port 22 connect ion.

Comment: This problem was reported to ansible in 2017. I've filed a new bug on github for this.https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71695

Comment: This response doest apply here, because ist not related to multiple hosts with different ssh args involved for every different host

Comment: you can choose to add different ssh args for each group_vars or host_vars file.

Comment: Thats interesting I will try when I go back monday, not sure if it will work with delegate to, but definitivly promising , thanks

Comment: That solution is working as expected with a moder version of ansible ( fails with older versions related to awx/tower)